# How do you set the default encoding in Jenkins?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, jenkins

I have a python script that outputs non-ascii characters.
It works fine from the command line (which has LANG en_US.UTF-8), but once I try to run it in Jenkins (launched from the same shell), it fails in the typical manner of an ascii terminal:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried preceeding the script call in the "Execute shell" build step like so:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

However, it seems to ignore that. Putting the following in my python script:

```
print "Encoding = %s" % sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Gives me this, no matter what I do:

```
Encoding = ascii
```

So is there something that will allow me to force Jenkins to use UTF-8?

Comment: I'd be interested in a more general answer to this question. I think the Python hack below doesn't work for Python 3.x...

Comment: If you are using Jenkins pipelin use `pipeline {
    agent {label 'nodename'}
    environment {
        LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
        LANG    = 'en_US.UTF-8'
        LANGUAGE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
 ...   }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never mind, found out how to do it:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

Comment: where in jenkins did you set this?

Comment: You add that line in the "execute shell" build step before calling the python script. Python doesn't look at the LANG environment variable, but it does look at the PYTHONIOENCODING variable.

Comment: You don't have to do it for every script. Instead set PYTHONIOENCODING to UTF-8 in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Environment variables > Add. It's not necessary to restart Jenkins for it to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the encoding on a system level in your Jenkins installation, you can add it as a global properties key-value pair (Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System) with `name=LANG` and `value=<insert your locale here>` (which in my case equals `en_GB.UTF-8`). That way you avoid setting the locale for every Jenkins job.

Comment: For Jenkins 2.60.2: After trying all the options here, I began trying combinations. Storing `PYTHONIOENCODING`:`UTF-8` as an environment variable did finally work.

Comment: Thank you TemporalWolf, that fixed the issue for me. I was completely stuck for awhile.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Jenkins Pipeline, you need to set the encoding within the pipeline as:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'node name'}
    environment {
        LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
        LANG    = 'en_US.UTF-8'
        LANGUAGE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    }
    stages {
        stage ('XXXX') {
            steps {
                 echo 'Hello'
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

did not work for me. However,

`export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

did.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was: **upgrade to the latest version** of Jenkins.  It seems the latest version respects the system locale settings.  See, eg, [this patch](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/775) maybe?

In any case, the default that shipped with Ubuntu 13.10 was out of date. Pulling down the latest version from their official debian repo fixed it for me!

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to use Python 3

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.3
pyenv local 3.7.3
make virtualenv
```

Comment: This error only appears *if* you are using Python 3, so this won't help much.