# Python error : UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, encoder

I have a python script in which a function prints some lines from error file.

Getting below error when I execute the script through jenkins.

```
release/bin/eat2/eat.py", line 553, in _runtest
    print('ERROR:' + msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0447' in position 315: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Default encoding for python is UTF-8

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

I tried to export the variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` before executing the script.

Added below line at the start of script-

```
# coding: utf8

def _check_gpderrors(gdplogfile):
    LOGERROR_REGEX = re.compile("^\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ Error:")

    errors = []
    import codecs
    f = codecs.open(logfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    for line in f:
        if re.match(LOGERROR_REGEX, line):
            errors.append(line.strip())
    f.close()
    return errors

errors = {}
errors = _check_gdperrors(log_file)
for error in errors:
        msg = project_info + ': execution failed with error: ' + error + '\n'
        print('ERROR:' + msg)
        logs.append(msg)
        script_error = True
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the logfile that you're open?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28927111/913522) answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use:

```
print('ERROR:' + msg.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

More info : [UnicodeEncodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: Thanks for the reply C.med
If my default python encoder is UTF-8, why it is throwing such error- 'ascii' codec can't encode character. From where exactly it is picking ascii encoder.

Comment: Yes, your default encoding is utf-8, but you are using an external file. they're two different things. (your file could be encoded differently). Another thing, your msg is `msg = project_info + ': execution failed with error: ' + error + '\n'`. Are you sure that `project_info` is an encoded text?

Comment: Thanks, above code worked but it ignores the accent characters and does'nt print it

Comment: Yes it's not really recommended to ignore `ascii`   like that. Try to reuse your code by adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your script.