# Python 2 to 3 migration - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character ...: ordinal not in range

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, encoding, migration

I am currently migrating a web application, written in Flask (Python 2.7) to Python 3. So far, I have managed to get everything working, but there is one small cosmetic bit that absolutely confuses me and I can't fix it.

This is a file that runs a static analysis on the code - `run_pylint.py`. I am going to shorten the file a bit with the important stuff on.

```
RESULT_EXPRESSION = re.compile(r'Your code has been rated at (\d*\.*\d*)/10')

VALIDATION_PERFECT = "✓ Pylint validation SUCCESSFUL! Perfect score!"
# and a couple of other options...

class PyLintOutput:
    """
    Pylint report storage and retrieval
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the storage"""
        self.content = []
        self.rate = None

    ... # skipping several unimportant methods

def get_rate(self):
    """
    After having been fed with PyLint output (via read()),
    determine the rate given to the module by PyLint.
    :return: A float between 0 (worst) to 10 (no issues detected).
    """
    if self.rate is not None:
        return self.rate

    for line in reversed(self.read()):
        result = re.search(RESULT_EXPRESSION, line)
        if result is None:
            continue

        self.rate = float(result.group(1))
        return self.rate

    return 0

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Get the full Pylint output as a string.
        """
        return "".join(self.content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # instance of the class
    OUT = PyLintOutput()

    # run PyLint static code analysis
    Run([MODULE_NAME], reporter=TextReporter(OUT), do_exit=False)

    if OUT.get_rate() < THRESHOLD:
        # if under threshold it prints a message to fix the bugs..
    elif OUT.get_rate() == THRESHOLD:
        # imperfect validation
    else:
        # perfect score
        print(VALIDATION_PERFECT)
```

I hope the idea is clear. So let's say the score is indeed perfect, so it goes to the else condition, which should print the message:

```
✓ Pylint validation SUCCESSFUL! Perfect score!
```

It does so in my console (I am using PyCharm). However, for deploying this web application I use Docker and Jenkins. Brief explanation: A docker container running centOS with Python 3.6, which builds the web application. One of the steps in building the web application is the static code analysis. If it fails, the deployment fails. All of this deployment happens in a single Jenkins job. This is the console log, when it reaches the exact same step, I mentioned above:

```
[91mTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_pylint.py", line 123, in <module>
    print(VALIDATION_PERFECT)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2713' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am not sure why it doesn't appear in my console the same way. I fixed similar problems with other parts of the code during the migration. So naturally, I tried a bunch of different stuff, including:

1)

```
    VALIDATION_PERFECT = u"✓ Pylint validation SUCCESSFUL! Perfect score!"
...
else:
     print(VALIDATION_PERFECT.encode("utf8))

Now, the tests pass, but the string is shown like this (in a bytes format):
 b'\xe2\x9c\x93 Pylint validation SUCCESSFUL! Perfect score!'
```

I tried decoding this, so it can become a normal Python 3 string, but nope, same error as above.

2) I ran accross a function in Stack Overflow that I used, however it gave me the same error:

```
def safeStr(obj):
    try: return str(obj)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return obj.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    except: return ""
```

3) I tried different combinations of encoding/decoding in "utf8", but to no success. I know that unicode is now supported in normal string in Python 3 and all of the thigns I tried, work in my console, when I locally execute this script. However, the problem persists in my Jenkins job.

Can anyone give me any tips?

Comment: Why not remove the `✓` character from that `VALIDATION_PERFECT` string and be done with it?  Sorry, I'm not being flippant here, but just trying to judge wether you *want* that character in the output from the Jenkins job, thus are looking for a workaround to the error.

Comment: @v25 I am trying to solve this problem, I have not said its urgent or anything, but it might come up later as an actual critical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076347/3324095) answer, you need to set the PYTHONENCODING environment variable on your Jenkins server.  Apparently, it can either be done in the Jenkins management console or, prior to calling your python validation script, you can execute this in the shell:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```